# Hibernate unable to map many students to a class

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I hae 2 simple entities: Student and Class. I want to POST a student, where I specify the class it belongs to, but I've got stuck in hibernate mapping.

**ClassModel.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "class" )
public class ClassModel implements Serializable {


@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@NotEmpty
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "tables")
private int tables;

@Column(name = "chairs")
private int chairs;

@Column(name = "teacher")
private String teacher;
(getters + setters)
```

**StudentModel**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class StudentModel implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "student_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int student_id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "name")
@Size(max = 50)
private String name;

@Column(name = "age")
private int age;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private ClassModel classModel;
(getters + setters)
}
```

**StudentController.java**

```
...
@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;

@Autowired
private ClassService classService;

@PostMapping(value = "/save")
public StudentModel save(@RequestBody StudentModel studentModel){
    ClassModel classModel = classService.findById(studentModel.getClassId()).get();
    studentModel.setClassModel(classModel);
    return studentService.save(studentModel);
}
...
```

But when I make a request from Postman with the following body:

```
{
    "name": "some name",
    "age": 12,
    "class_id": 1
}
```

I get the following error from hibernate:

```
Column 'class_id' cannot be null
```

Where is the mistake in my hibernate mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's how I have made working join in hibernate. Have a look:

**TrainingEntity.java**

```
@Id
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "animal_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private AnimalEntity animalEntity;

@Column(name = "animal_id")
private Integer animalId;
```

**AnimalEntity.java**

```
@Id
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "animalEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<TrainingEntity> trainingEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
```

So here is the join between AnimalEntity and TrainingEntity.
AnimalEntity have a list of TrainingEntities.

Comment: Happy to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in this line:

```
"class_id": 1
```

You're using column name instead of field name. You would have to replace `class_id` with `classModel`, where `classModel` would be an object. Other solution would be to find `ClassModel` by id from json and set it as parent to `StudentModel`.

Comment: I have refactored the code, and now I get the error : "Unknown column 'id' ", about the private ClassModel classModel in StudentModel

Comment: @AndrewT I would need to see the code you're using to save it

Comment: I am updating the question to include the controller